# Filling in a blank space in relation to surrounding pixels

Tags: java, image-processing, coordinates, bufferedimage

I am currently working on a program that preforms techniques such as image segmentation along with a few others. However I have the task ahead of me of filling a segmented area (this will be a blank area) based on its surrounding pixels.

This is a lot like what photoshop likes to call [content aware fill](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJblbu4g_xQ), however me being only one person am wondering the best way I could approach this type task. Also how I should start to think about getting something, obviously not as technical and robust, but similar in some sense to work.

I am not currently aware of any classes that may help with something like this but any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are after [Inpainting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting). There are many ways to do it, and an [Inpainting survey](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~masnou/fichiers/publications/survey.pdf) by Bertalmío, Caselles, Masnou, Sapiro - 2011, presents lots of results and references about them.

Around here you will also find sample results using the technique, for instance at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13666082/1832154 you will see one together with http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~sooraj/inpainting/ that gives a complete implementation. At https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295915/1832154 you can see another sample result, together with a simplistic reference to a different inpainting method.

Comment: I have been attempting to work out how to implement the implementation of inpainting that is used within the link you provided in your post. http://elynxsdk.free.fr/ext-docs/Inpainting/todo/Fast_Digital_Image_Inpainting.pdf however I have been a little bit confused, is this simply going over the segmented part of the image with the weighted average kernals?
sorry if this is a bit of a silly question and thanks for the advice pointing me into the correct direction for what I need to do.

Comment: At http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~sooraj/inpainting/ there is a ready implementation of a different method. For this simpler algorithm you mention, the answer is yes if there is no misunderstanding about how it is done. It is not a segmented part per se, it is a mask defined somehow. And the method is iterative.